# openlayers starter: setCenter on rcp1_map

Tags: openlayers

dear openlayers experts: I started with the first example in the openlayers cookbook (uneven; is there a better one?), changed the zoom max to a setCenter call, and tried it.  the zoom works, the center does not.  its probably a real simple problem, but perplexing to a novice.  I also am not sure where rcp1_map lives, which presumably is the world map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
              src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <style> html, body { width: 80%; height: 80%; margin: 1em; padding: 1em; } </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("rcp1_map");
            var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
            map.addLayer(osm);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(34.05,118.25), 5);
        }
    </script>
    </head>

<body onload="init()">
    <h1>Hello, Los Angeles</h1>
    <div id="rcp1_map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and, instead of rcp1_map, should or could I download a complete world map down to street level somewhere and install it?

starter advice appreciated.

/iaw

Answer (score 0):

First, if you define your map before you call the `onload="init()"` as in:

```
var map;
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("rcp1_map");
    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    map.addLayer(osm);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(34.05,118.25), 5);
}
```

Then the setCenter will work. The problem is you are entering coordinates in google coordinates now. See http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html.

The coordinates of Los Angeles in Google Mercator would be -13180189,4018753. Have a look at http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ to see what the coordinates of things are in Google Mercator.

As for `rcp1_map`, that is the id of the div the map goes into within the body of your page.

Here is the final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<style> html, body { width: 80%; height: 80%; margin: 1em; padding: 1em; } </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("rcp1_map");
        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(osm);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-13180189,4018753), 5);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<h1>Hello, Los Angeles</h1>
<div id="rcp1_map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: helps a lot!  thank you.  the "var map" before the init does not seem to change anything.

most important: your new coordinates worked--and now I understand what was wrong!  is there a function to convert from LL to M?  I tried **var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(34.05,118.25); map.setCenter(point.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject()), 5);** but that failed.

where is rcp1_map?  is it at openlayers.org (via OpenLayers.js)? should my own site host it instead?

(and, is there a starter book you would recommend?)

Comment: I have had problems unless I define map before the init().

Comment: Try `point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-118.25,34.05);` for your point. Your lon lat were reversed and you also need negative in the western hemisphere

Comment: thanks again.  this one worked.  interesting: libs do not modulus the coordinates.

Comment: still looking for a good starter book.  the first code in http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html (example ex1 stuck into the template) gives me an undefined in the javascript console.  grr....